# Simple controller make angular doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Hello I am learning angular 1 and I have problem at the very beggining.

I'm trying to display data with table in ng-repeat using controller. Angular in app stops working at all even {{ 2 + 2 }} on bottom of page doesn't work. I can't find the reason why.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <title>SZYBKI START Z BRACKETS</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="aplikacja">
<div class="container" ng-controller="kontrolerTabeliSkoczkow">
    <h1 class="text-center">Klasyfikacja skoczków narciarskich</h1>

    <br />

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Szukaj: </span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="np. Adam Małysz" />
    </div>

    <br />

    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th ng-repeat="naglowek in [
                                   'Imię', 'Rok urodzenia', 'Narodowość'
                                   ]">{{ naglowek }}</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="skoczkowie in skoczkow">
                    <td>{{skoczek.Name}}</td>
                    <td>{{skoczek.Nation}}</td>
                    <td>{{skoczek.rank}}</td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>

{{ 2+2 }}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('aplikacja', []);

    app.contoller( 'kontrolerTabeliSkoczkow' , ['$scope', function( $scope ) {
        $scope.skoczkowie = [
         {
           "Name": "HIRSCHER Marcel",
           "Nation": "AUT",
           "rank": 1
         },
         {
           "Name": "JANSRUD Kjetil",
           "Nation": "NOR",
           "rank": 2
         }
        ]
    }];
</script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>    

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's typo mistake, change

```
app.contoller(...)
```

to

```
app.controller(...)
```

and close properly:

```
app.controller("kontrolerTabeliSkoczkow" , ['$scope', function( $scope ) { ... }]);
```

see link [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/avnesh2/fygLzv5e/)

Comment: Well angular back to work but table is still empty so i guess something is still wrong

Comment: skoczek in skoczkowie insted of skoczkowie in skoczkow and it's work fine :)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close the controller.

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('aplikacja', []);

    app.contoller( 'kontrolerTabeliSkoczkow' , ['$scope', function( $scope ) {
        $scope.skoczkowie = [
         {
           "Name": "HIRSCHER Marcel",
           "Nation": "AUT",
           "rank": 1
         },
         {
           "Name": "JANSRUD Kjetil",
           "Nation": "NOR",
           "rank": 2
         }
        ]
    }]);
</script>
```

(The ')' at the very end)

Also, I would declare Jquery BEFORE angular

Answer (score 0):

A parenthesis is missing just between the `]}` and `;` at the end of your controller
Furthermore, I do not recommand using this notation, just don't declare dependencies in your controller, I recommand doing it this way :

```
app.controller("kontrolerTabeliSkoczkow", function($scope){
    /*anything you want to put in it*/
});
```

You don't get confused by parenthesis, brackets and stuff, just declare your dependencies in your module, not in your controller